# Selenium check if element exits and click

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I'm using **Selenium** and **Scrapy** to scrape contents from a dynamic website. I'm newbie to **Selenium**. I'm extracting wine list from [here](http://www.vivino.com/wineries/francis-ford-coppola/). The site has a `show more` button which when clicked displays further lists of wine. As for now, i'm only able to click the button once and extract the wine list. But i need to click the button every time until `show more` button is not displayed. Any help on this would be hugely appreciated. Here is my code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import time




class WineSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "wspider"
    allowed_domains = ["vivino.com"]



    start_urls = ["http://www.vivino.com/wineries/francis-ford-coppola/"] #hloru
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self,response):

        sel = Selector(self.driver.get(response.url))

        self.driver.get(response.url)
        links = []

        time.sleep(5)

        #this is for selecting the show more button

        click = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn-more-wines']")
        click[0].click()
        time.sleep(5)
        wines = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class = "link-muted"]')
        for w in wines:
                links.append(w.get_attribute("href"))



        print len(links)
        self.driver.close()
```

Any help would be really useful.

Answer (score 3):

Make an endless loop, use an [`Explicit Wait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for "Show More" button to appear, break the loop once "Show More" is not visible anymore (no more wines left) - only then parse the results:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.vivino.com/wineries/francis-ford-coppola/")

while True:
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "btn-more-wines")))
    except TimeoutException:
        break  # no more wines

    button.click()  # load more wines


wines = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class = "link-muted"]')

links = [w.get_attribute("href") for w in wines]

driver.close()
```

Note that an Explicit Wait is really a game changer here - it would make your code more reliable and fast comparing to having hardcoded time.sleep delays.

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I would try doing the following.
Keep the action emulation, that is in you case clicking of the show-more button in a separate function like,

```
def emulate_action(self):
try:
    click = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn-more-wines']")
    click[0].click()
    time.sleep(5.0)
    return True

except ElementNotVisibleException as e:
    print " All elements displayed"
    return False
```

And then call it until all the wine list has been loaded,

```
while 1:

flag = self.emulate_action()

if (res):
    continue
else:
    break
```

then this section of code going after that should hopefully solve your problem if I am not wrong.

```
wines = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class = "link-muted"]')
    for w in wines:
            links.append(w.get_attribute("href"))



    print len(links)
    self.driver.close()
```

Let me know if this method works for you!